# jquery-ui autocomplete breaks browser storage of filled form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, browser, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using jquery and jquery-ui autocomplete in a form. The problem is that if the user fills out the form, then navigatets to a different page, then comes back to the form, all the fields will still be filled, except the one with the autocomplete, which will be blank.

I've drilled it down to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){ $("#ac_box").autocomplete({
    source: ("tatooine dagobah hoth bespin yavin alderaan ry'leh kessel nar-shadda".split(' '))})
   };*
</script>
...
<form><input type="text" id="ac_box"></form>
```

will display the problem, but removing the script makes it go away (text stays in the field when leaving the page and returning). I've played around with the autocomplete options, but I could certainly have missed something.

Also, it appears this may be different in different browsers. I get the problem in a recent version of chrome on mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that browsers tie the behavior of remembering form values when navigating to the built-in autocomplete behavior. Therefore, turning off the native autocomplete stops the browser from remembering the value when navigating back to the page.

Since the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget disables the native autocomplete, it also unintentionally disables the browser's ability to remember the field's value while navigating. If you re-enable the native autocomplete before the page unloads, the browser will remember the value.

I just landed a fix for this, so it should start working properly in 1.8.17. In the meantime, you can add this to your pages to fix the problem:

```
$( window ).bind( "beforeunload", function() {
    $( ".ui-autocomplete-input" ).removeAttr( "autocomplete" );
});
```

- jQuery UI bug: [#7790](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7790)
- Fix in master:
  [81b2ef4a6088cb99863c2d318947355a58019362](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/81b2ef4a6088cb99863c2d318947355a58019362)
- Fix in 1-8-stable:
  [b41873ba0dd8f84ec282f77d029c7dc0ee99b873](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/b41873ba0dd8f84ec282f77d029c7dc0ee99b873)

Comment: This fix breaks the app's own custom `onbeforeunload` listeners.  Bad.  See the comments in Bug #7790.  Will the fix be fixed?